# Security - Giving Apache write access to /var/www/html

Tags: permissions, security, apache-httpd, vsftpd, wordpress

I am running Worpdress on an CentOS Webserver.

Now, to enable wordpress to be able to upload/write files to the default webserver directory

```
/var/www/html
```

I had to do the following change on the server as root user:

```
[user@host ~]$ chown apache /path/to/upload/dir
[user@host ~]$ chmod 755 /path/to/upload/dir
```

What security implications does this have?

I know I can move all my files to say the /home/ directory and point Apache to it, but it is too much effort...

Can I keep it like this or it it unsafe to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. I had to do the same on my setup as well so that files could be uploaded.

The biggest risk is that if there is a vulnerability in Wordpress, then this is a directory that a would be attacker could put payloads. But arguably they've already gained access to your Wordpress installation so you're already in trouble.

Part of the price of maintaining a Wordpress installation is that you have to keep up with the updates.

Comment: OK cool, thank you. that makes sense. I have one more problem however - I cannot edit any files in wordpress - say i want to edit the style.css, it says: You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes. See the Codex for more information

Comment: @DextrousDave - yes you'll need to make those files writable as well for the user that the web server is running as - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/making-wordpress-css-stylesheet-writeable

Comment: @DextrousDave - not sure if you should've started this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82309/centos-issue-with-write-permissions, they're too related/similar. Bottom line is you're having a permissions problem.

Comment: @DextrousDave - if this answers your question please mark it as accepted if it resolved your question so that others know that it's been resolved.